# How to support low data mode in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, networking, ios13

"Low Data Mode" is introduced in iOS 13. See "Settings" section [Apple's iOS 13 overview](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-13-preview/features/):

> [image: Low Data Mode]

I couldn't find any developer documentation on this.

Is this something third party app developers can opt into, [as suggested by MacRumors](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/use-low-data-mode/)? Or is will it just suspend background activity when not connected to Wi-Fi, [as suggested by AppleInsider](https://appleinsider.com/articles/19/06/16/13-hidden-ios-13-features-you-didnt-know-about)?

Comment: iOS will suspend things like background refresh and It is something that your app can support - https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/712/

Comment: Does the video explain how to support it in your app?

Comment: Sort of.  It explains how to detect that you are connected to a low data mode network- what you do in your app is up to you; You might not load images or video by default or you might load lower resolution images; It depends on what your app does.

Comment: Check. I'll watch the video later and will post the answer below.

Answer (score 7):

To determine if iOS is currently in Low Data mode, you can use the Network library:

```
import Network // Put this on top of your class

let monitor = NWPathMonitor()

monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in

    if path.isConstrained {
        // Path uses an interface in Low Data Mode.
    }
    else if path.isExpensive {
        // Path uses an interface that is considered expensive, such as Cellular or a Personal Hotspot.
    }
}

monitor.start(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
```

Comment: Can also just use `monitor.currentPath.isConstrained`

Answer (score 3):

URLSession supports **LowData** mode in iOS 13.

Steps

- Provide two different resources for high resolution and low resolution(low data mode)
- If `statusCode == 200` (low data mode is disabled in setting).
- If `error.networkAvailableReason == .constrained` (low data mode is enable in settings)

Check out [Advances in Networking, Part 1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/712/?time=959) from WWDC 2019 from 16:00 for a demo and sample code. You can use Combine to make the code simpler, but this is not required.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to configure your `URLSession` (`NSURLSession`) to either allow or disallow `expensive` or `constrained` network connections to be opened.

You can do that by changing URLSession's respective properties `allowsExpensiveNetworkAccess` or `allowsConstrainedNetworkAccess` to `false` (`NO`).

If a `URLSessionTask` results in an error that is either an `NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet` error containing `NSURLErrorNetworkUnavailableReasonKey` entry in `userInfo` (Objective-C) or an `URLError` with a non-nil `NetworkUnavailableReason` property set (Swift), then you need to act accordingly.

Those reasons can be:

- `expensive`
- `constrained`
- `cellular`

The `cellular` reason has sort of been there since iOS 7, so it's not new, but the entire `reason` enumeration is, as Apple streamlined connection type handling a bit this year.

Comment: And when do we set that property? How do we know low data mode is on or off?

Comment: Set those properties when you're configuring your URLSession, before making any requests. I don't know if there are ways to check whether the low power mode is on - it's a little more complicated than that. There are at least two "modes" current network can be in - it can be both expensive and constrained.

Comment: So you set the property `allowsConstrainedNetworkAccess` to `false` and act on the resulted error if present. Check.

Comment: @macbirdie it looks like `allowsConstrainedNetworkAccess` property exists on `URLRequest` instead of _URLSession_. 
 -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlrequest/3358305-allowsexpensivenetworkaccess

Comment: It's also there in the `URLSessionConfiguration` which you use to _configure_ the `URLSession`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution in Xamarin, for those interested:

```
NWPathMonitor monitor = new NWPathMonitor();
monitor.SetUpdatedSnapshotHandler(path =>
    {
        if (path.Status == NWPathStatus.Satisfied)
        {
            if(path.IsConstrained)
            {
             // Path uses an interface in Low Data Mode.
            }
        }
    });
monitor.SetQueue(CoreFoundation.DispatchQueue.DefaultGlobalQueue);
monitor.Start();
```