# SCNetworkReachabilityFlags returns Wifi but it's cellular

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using SCNetworkReachabilityFlags for checking network status.
My app needs to check the network is connectable or connected on wifi or connected on cellular.
Almost all of devices are working correctly. But a few of device are working incorrectly. Even though they work with the same code.
The SCNetworkReachabilityFlags of the device not working correctly returns Wifi but wifi is turned off and the device is connected on cellular. So it makes my app's flow wrong.
SCNetworkReachabilityFlags is an iOS System value. So I don't even know what I have to do to resolve this issue.

Does anyone know about this issue? or solution?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Checking for WiFi vs cellular is probably the wrong thing anyway.  You can be on a WiFi network which is still expensive/constrained (e.g. Hotspot)  Check for [low data mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56886273/how-to-support-low-data-mode-in-ios-13/56988795)

Comment: @Paulw11 Unfortunately my app is support from iOS 11. So I don't use that low data mode. But Thank you for your reply.

Comment: There is no flag that indicates WiFi.  If your logic is to determine WiFi based on the absence of the `isWWAN` flag, then this is [incorrect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/scnetworkreachabilityflags/1618595-iswwan).  The `isWWAN` flag indicates that a cellular connection can be used to connect to the endpoint.  *The absence of this flag doesn't mean that a cellular connection won't be used*

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the reason why this issue happened but found solution.
It's just use AFNetworkReachabilityManager.
It has valuables isReachableViaWiFi and isReachableViaWWAN.
The device still returns Wifi but AFNetworkReachabilityManager returns WWAN correctly. It would be better if I found the solution or the exact reason about this issue, but for me, the solution is much more important now. So Anyone knows about this issue, please share your knowledge for someone who would need information about this.

Comment: `AFNetworkingReachabilityManager` simply relies on `kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN`.  Perhaps you have a bug in your previous implementation?  Regardless, the note from Apple still applies; The lack of this flag does not indicate that the connection is via WiFi.  I suggest that you start to adopt `NWPathMonitor` and only fallback to reachability on iOS 11 (A vanishingly small percentage of devices)

Comment: @Paulw11Actually, this code is not mine. the prodecessor developer used kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsDirect as Wifi. And it works most of devices so I thought it means Wifi. But that's my fault I didn't check again. I also want to stop support this iOS 11 but our little tiny users are still using that version. But I'll start to adopt NWPathMonitor someday as you mentioned. Thank you!

Comment: That's even worse - that flag means that the specified host is on the same network as the device (it is on a a network directly connected to the device, doesn't go via a gateway).  As you have found it is possible for the device to be WiFi connected but not directly connected.