In macOS, how do I detect low data mode in command line or Python?
I want to write a script that executes only if the low data mode is turned off on the network adapter. But I can't find a solution on Google. Is it possible to write such the check in a script?
I have Sonoma (14.4.1).

If low data mode is on, do nothing.

here is a related answer in swift, not python https://stackoverflow.com/a/58048051/5666087
